# pgAdmin 4 don't find existing local servers and no "Connect to server" option

Tags: pgadmin-4

I created my local server and databases with pgAdmin 3 two weeks ago.
I installed pgAdmin 4 and when opened my servers are not there and neither the Object/Connect option.
How can I retrive existing server configuration?
Thanks in advance
Marcos

Comment: Currently there is no option to export server list from pgAdmin3 to pgAdmin4. You have to manually add your servers in pgAdmin4. You can add servers by right clicking on "Servers" on left side panel and select option Create Server to add new server.